# How can I create a Sierpinski triangle (fractal)?

Tags: php, algorithm, fractals

I need to program a Sierpinski triangle with PHP which gives the following image output:

[image]

I really do not know where to start this with, so any form of algorithms or ideas are welcome.

Comment: Start learning about `php` image library.

Comment: Try canvas, here you have an example: http://jsfiddle.net/HEWkZ/3/

Comment: Thanks bro I ll read em

Comment: I would suggest learning and understanding the Sierpinski algorithm first _then_ spend time with the PHP graphic library. Languages and graphic libraries might change in the future, but the algorithm stays the same.

Comment: I don't see what's too broad in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Given the coordinates of the vertices of the outer triangle, you can easily find the coordinates of the vertices of the large empty triangle (they are the midpoint of the edges).

So from the outer triangle, you can build the three large non-empty triangles.

The Sierpinski triangle is obtained by repeating this process a number of times, recursively. When you reach the desired recursion depth, you just draw the triangle.

In pseudocode:

```
Sierpinski(P, Q, R, Depth):
    if Depth == Limit:
        Line(P, Q); Line(Q, R); Line(R, P)
    else:
        PQ= (P + Q) / 2; QR= (Q + R) / 2; RP= (R + P) / 2;
        Sierpinski(P, PQ, RP, Depth + 1);
        Sierpinski(Q, QR, PQ, Depth + 1);
        Sierpinski(R, RP, QR, Depth + 1);
```